# Grape API Arrays of Hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-grape, grape-api

I am using the grape gem version 0.19.0.

I am passing the following data:

```
{references: [{x: '10'}, {x: '20'}, {x: '30'}]}
```

The validation section on the server is:

```
params do
  optional :references, type: Array do
    optional :x, type: String
  end
end
```

This does not enter my API call on the server and the client gets the following response:

```
responseText: "{"error":"references is invalid"}"
```

How do I pass an array of hashes?

Comment: when you put a breakpoint at the top of that does the data make it into the validation section?

Comment: No it does not.  (That is what I meant by it does not enter the API call on the server.)

Comment: I was reading the docs, and I found you can use `Array`, try with: `optional :references, type: Array[Hash]`

Comment: I just found something else: `Depending on the value, the nested parameters will be treated either as values of a hash or as values of hashes in an array`. So: `optional :references, type: Array do` `requires :key` `requires :value` `end`. There are examples in the docs https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape

Comment: I read that as `type: Array do` vs `type: Hash do`.  I have tried Hash, but it does not take an array.